# C++ - Stuck with YoloV4, ONNX and TensorRT

Tags: c++, tensorrt

I'm doing some detection using YoloV4/C++/OpenCV and it's running pretty good.
Hower, to improve time consumption I'm trying to move everything to NVIDIA TensorRT and I'm feeling lost there.

I converted the .weights file to ONNX using the TensorRT tools, then converted the ONNX model to TensorRT engine like this :

```cpp
void ONNXConvert()
{
    MyLogger logger;
    nvinfer1::IBuilder* builder = nvinfer1::createInferBuilder(logger);
    nvinfer1::INetworkDefinition* network = builder->createNetworkV2(1U << static_cast<int>(nvinfer1::NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag::kEXPLICIT_BATCH));

    // Load ONNX model
    const auto parser = nvonnxparser::createParser(*network, logger);

    // Parse the ONNX model
    // Some code here...

    std::ifstream onnxFile(onnxModelFile, std::ios::binary);
    if (!onnxFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening ONNX model file. " << onnxModelFile << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    onnxFile.seekg(0, onnxFile.end);
    const size_t modelSize = onnxFile.tellg();
    onnxFile.seekg(0, onnxFile.beg);

    // Allocate buffer to hold the ONNX model
    std::vector<char> onnxModelBuffer(modelSize);
    onnxFile.read(onnxModelBuffer.data(), modelSize);

    if (!parser->parse(onnxModelBuffer.data(), modelSize))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error parsing ONNX model." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Create a builder configuration
    nvinfer1::IBuilderConfig* config = builder->createBuilderConfig();

    // Set configuration options as needed
    config->setMemoryPoolLimit(nvinfer1::MemoryPoolType::kWORKSPACE, 1 << 30);

    nvinfer1::IHostMemory* serializedEngine = builder->buildSerializedNetwork(*network, *config);
    std::cout << "Number of layers in the network: " << network->getNbLayers() << std::endl;
    std::ofstream outFile("yolov4.engine", std::ios::binary);
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(serializedEngine->data()), serializedEngine->size());
    outFile.close();

    builder->destroy();
    network->destroy();
    serializedEngine->destroy();
}
```

This done, I can load the generated engine and perform the inference, everything seems to goes well until I try to parse the detection results.

I want to know the classes probabilities and the bounding boxes coordinates, but everything I have is inconsistent values.

From my YoloV4 config, I know I have :

- 20 classes
- Input width = 608
- Input height = 608
- Channels = 3
- 9 anchors with dimensions { 12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28, 36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146, 142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401 }

After the inference, I have 2 output buffers :

- a 1x22743x1x4 where I guess I will find the bounding boxes coordinates
- a 1x22743x20 where I guess I will find the classes probabilities

And this where I'm getting lost.
Why are there 22743 detections ? How is this number calculated ?
How must I parse the detections to correctly compute the coordinates and classes probabilities ?

I innocently tried to directly parse the outputs like that :

```cpp
for (int d = 0; d < 22743; d++)
{
    float maxProb = -1000.0f;
    int classId = -1;
    for (int c = 0; c < 20; c++)
    {
        if (classes[d * 20 + c] > maxProb)
        {
            maxProb = classes[d * 20 + c];
            classId = c;
        }
    }

    if (maxProb > CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD)
    {
        float boxX = boxes[d * 4];
        float boxY = boxes[d * 4 + 1];
        float boxW = boxes[d * 4 + 2];
        float boxH = boxes[d * 4 + 3];
    }
}
```

But everything I got is tiny probabilities (like < 1E-05), and tiny and sometimes negatives boxes coordinates.

I understand I'm supposed to use what I know about the anchors but I'm really not sure how.

Could someone give me hand about that ? Every help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Searching for "yolov4 22743" at least gives an [explanation for the number](https://medium.com/data-reply-it-datatech/yolo-v3-for-object-detection-f9f5637cf428): 22743 is the sum of detection results for a grid size of 19x19, 38x38 and 76x76. There can be three bounding boxes for every element on the grid, so the final tally is `22743 = 3 * (19*19 + 38*38 + 76*76)`

Comment: @Botje Sounds like a pretty good lead, thank you !